# Linux 'add_interrupt_randomness' implementation - low entropy contribution by cycles and jiffies?

Tags: linux, random, entropy, kernel

Currently I'm analyzing the process of entropy generation of a Linux 64-bit kernel during system startup (for educational purpose). The system is hosted as/on a (64 bit) virtual machine (Xen domU). For a deep analysis, I'm tracking the state of relevant input parameters i.e. how those are processed. In function `add_interrupt_randomness` I found some code whose intention is not clear to me: The handling of `cycles` (value provided by CPU cycles counter) and `now` (jiffies). Both are unsigned 64 bit values, and processed as following:

```
c_high = (sizeof(cycles) > 4) ? cycles >> 32 : 0;
j_high = (sizeof(now) > 4) ? now >> 32 : 0;
fast_pool->pool[0] ^= cycles ^ j_high ^ irq;
```

So `c_high`/`j_high` `(__u32)` are assigned with the upper 32 bit of `cycles`/`now` and then assigned (after XOR) to the fast entropy pool.
Hence a maximum variation of the values provided by `c_high` and `j_high` should be desirable?. But since `c_high` and `j_high` are based on `cycles` and `now`/jiffies, ,which are purely incremented variables, there is very little/no variation in the upper 32-bits as the traced values reveal:

**Values in call no. 1 of add_interrupt_randomness:**

```
cycles:0xFFFEA432A6C2CB89
c_high:0xFFFEA432
now_jiffies:0x00000000FFFEDB0A
j_high:0x00000000
```

**Values in call no. 4265* of add_interrupt_randomness:**

```
cycles:0xFFFEA43FBA85B313
c_high:0xFFFEA43F
now_jiffies:0x00000000FFFEE80C
j_high:0x00000000
```

*(startup is completed at this point)

During the system start `add_interrupt_randomness` is called 4265 times. The value of `j_high` is constantly `0x00000000`, the value of `c_high` 
increments from `0xFFFEA432` to `0xFFFEA43F`.
So my question is: **why are the upper 32 bits processed instead of the lower, which would provide more randomness?**

If interested: this is the complete definition of `add_interrupt_randomness`:

```
void add_interrupt_randomness(int irq, int irq_flags)
{
    struct entropy_store    *r;
    struct fast_pool    *fast_pool = this_cpu_ptr(&irq_randomness);
    struct pt_regs      *regs = get_irq_regs();
    unsigned long       now = jiffies;
    cycles_t        cycles = random_get_entropy();
    __u32           c_high, j_high;
    __u64           ip;
    unsigned long       seed;
    int         credit = 0;

    if (cycles == 0)
        cycles = get_reg(fast_pool, regs);
    c_high = (sizeof(cycles) > 4) ? cycles >> 32 : 0;
    j_high = (sizeof(now) > 4) ? now >> 32 : 0;
    fast_pool->pool[0] ^= cycles ^ j_high ^ irq;
    fast_pool->pool[1] ^= now ^ c_high;
    ip = regs ? instruction_pointer(regs) : _RET_IP_;
    fast_pool->pool[2] ^= ip;
    fast_pool->pool[3] ^= (sizeof(ip) > 4) ? ip >> 32 :
        get_reg(fast_pool, regs);

    fast_mix(fast_pool);
    add_interrupt_bench(cycles);

    if (!crng_ready()) {
        if ((fast_pool->count >= 64) &&
            crng_fast_load((char *) fast_pool->pool,
                   sizeof(fast_pool->pool))) {
            fast_pool->count = 0;
            fast_pool->last = now;
        }
        return;
    }

    if ((fast_pool->count < 64) &&
        !time_after(now, fast_pool->last + HZ))
        return;

    r = &input_pool;
    if (!spin_trylock(&r->lock))
        return;

    fast_pool->last = now;
    __mix_pool_bytes(r, &fast_pool->pool, sizeof(fast_pool->pool));

    /*
     * If we have architectural seed generator, produce a seed and
     * add it to the pool.  For the sake of paranoia don't let the
     * architectural seed generator dominate the input from the
     * interrupt noise.
     */
    if (arch_get_random_seed_long(&seed)) {
        __mix_pool_bytes(r, &seed, sizeof(seed));
        credit = 1;
    }
    spin_unlock(&r->lock);

    fast_pool->count = 0;

    /* award one bit for the contents of the fast pool */
    credit_entropy_bits(r, credit + 1);
}
```

from: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.6/source/drivers/char/random.c#L1118

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**They are both processed.**

Both `cycles` and `now` are mixed into the fast pool in their entirety. See the relevant lines:

```
fast_pool->pool[0] ^= cycles ^ j_high ^ irq;
fast_pool->pool[1] ^= now ^ c_high;
```

In order to distribute randomness a bit, the number of CPU cycles<sup>*</sup> that have occurred since boot are mixed with the high bits of the number of jiffies, and the number of jiffies are mixed in with the high bits of the number of cycles. Even when this is happening, the full number of cycles and jiffies are inserted into the fast pool with the XOR operation. There is no `c_low` and `j_low`, but the bits *are* added.

The fast pool is [defined in the random driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.6/source/drivers/char/random.c#L574) as:

```
struct fast_pool {
    __u32           pool[4];
    unsigned long   last;
    unsigned short  reg_idx;
    unsigned char   count;
};
```

The fast pool contains an array of four 32-bit values. The cycle counter, stored as `cycles_t`, may be a 64-bit value as it is [defined as](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.6/source/include/asm-generic/timex.h#L8) an `unsigned long`, so writing just the cycle counter to one of the pool elements will discard the high bits. This is not ideal, so the high bits are obtained separately and put in their own 32-bit integer which is then added to the pool on its own, in effect preserving the entire 64-bit value despite only being able to mix in 32-bits at a time. As you can see with the following two lines, if the two values already fit in a single 32-bit integer, the (non-existent) high 32 bits are set to 0:

```
c_high = (sizeof(cycles) > 4) ? cycles >> 32 : 0;
j_high = (sizeof(now) > 4) ? now >> 32 : 0;
```

The process is thus:

1. If the variables are larger than 32 bits, save a copy of the high bits, otherwise set the copy to 0.
2. Mix in the variables with the fast pool, discarding the high bits during [integer conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34885966/9782169).
3. Mix in the saved high bits, in effect "folding" the low and high bits into a single 32-bit integer.

<sub>* On some architectures, such as [certain versions of MIPS](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.6/source/arch/mips/include/asm/timex.h#L87), the cycle counter may not be available.</sub>

---

Note that [commit ac2ab99072cc](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ac2ab99072cce553c78f326ea22d72856f570d88) has made numerous changes to the random driver, so the described implementation of the interrupt randomness mixing routines are now outdated:

```
@@ -1345,37 +1002,19 @@ static void mix_interrupt_randomness(struct work_struct *work)
 void add_interrupt_randomness(int irq)
 {
    enum { MIX_INFLIGHT = 1U << 31 };
-   unsigned long cycles = random_get_entropy(), now = jiffies;
+   unsigned long entropy = random_get_entropy();
    struct fast_pool *fast_pool = this_cpu_ptr(&irq_randomness);
    struct pt_regs *regs = get_irq_regs();
    unsigned int new_count;
-   union {
-       u32 u32[4];
-       u64 u64[2];
-       unsigned long longs[16 / sizeof(long)];
-   } irq_data;
-
-   if (cycles == 0)
-       cycles = get_reg(fast_pool, regs);
-
-   if (sizeof(unsigned long) == 8) {
-       irq_data.u64[0] = cycles ^ rol64(now, 32) ^ irq;
-       irq_data.u64[1] = regs ? instruction_pointer(regs) : _RET_IP_;
-   } else {
-       irq_data.u32[0] = cycles ^ irq;
-       irq_data.u32[1] = now;
-       irq_data.u32[2] = regs ? instruction_pointer(regs) : _RET_IP_;
-       irq_data.u32[3] = get_reg(fast_pool, regs);
-   }
 
-   fast_mix(fast_pool->pool, irq_data.longs);
+   fast_mix(fast_pool->pool, entropy,
+        (regs ? instruction_pointer(regs) : _RET_IP_) ^ swab(irq));
    new_count = ++fast_pool->count;
 
    if (new_count & MIX_INFLIGHT)
        return;
 
-   if (new_count < 64 && (!time_after(now, fast_pool->last + HZ) ||
-                  unlikely(crng_init == 0)))
+   if (new_count < 64 && !time_is_before_jiffies(fast_pool->last + HZ))
        return;
 
    if (unlikely(!fast_pool->mix.func))
```